# CENT OS xinetd service

Tags: xinetd

I want open pop3 port on my CENT OS Linux box with /etc/services. And add pop3 script on /etc/xinet.d/
After modifying that file, can't restart /etc/rc.d/init.d/xinetd.
There is no xinetd file in that directory.

How can i restart xinetd without xinetd startup script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install and activate the xinetd package.

```
yum install xinetd
chkconfig xinetd on
service xinetd start
```